# flex: Communicating between ActionScript and JavaScript in a desktop application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I'm using adobe builder 4.7, I want to run my html in flex desktop application, and I need to call some native flex api ( like File ) in my html javascript, so how to let them communicate? All the docs I found is to insert flex into html, not reverse.

The **ExternalInterface** is used in a flex web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following link will help you:-
http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/02/25/air-actionscript-javascript-bridge/